# Adding Content in lightbox popup & setting size

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have a page, where the product items are been displayed from database. I am able to add a lightbox effect to all the items. But, i want to also add the Product Name, Description, Product Qty, and Product Rate in the popup window of lightbox.

I tried doing it by title tag, it does come somehow, but when you hover the mouse on the image, the html code is also rendered of the title tag in the image For rg.

Is there any way to add the above mentioned details and also when the popup is showing the image, i want the image should be displayed in 200px X 200px, irrespective of what the original size is.

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: try http://fancybox.net/ it can display HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think on how to do it, is to create a separate `html/php` page that contains the needed image, name, description etc., anything you need from database, and open that page with [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) as `iframe` using this script:

```
$.fancybox({
  'href'  :  'url_to_your_image_page.php?imageid=15',
  'type'  :  'iframe'
});
```

Note the `imageid` variable, that will tell which image to load.

Comment: finally its solved by me!! Use Fancy box. it gives multiple options, apart from lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

finally its solved by me!! Use Fancy box. it gives multiple options, apart from lightbox.